# Regex - Powershell - Should be simple, but I can't make it to do what I want

Tags: regex, powershell

I have this simple requirements:

- Must start with letter (a-z)
- Rest can be numbers a-z and underscore
- No uppercase letters
- Length > 3 and < 9

This returns false, but should be true

```
'h8euj_' -match "(^[a-z][a-z0-9_]+)(i){4,8}"
```

What's wrong ?

Comment: At first glance, take out `(i)` and use `-cmatch`

Comment: Well, it is no doubt you have no match, `(i){4,8}` requires at least four consecutive `i`s after one or more alphanumeric and `_` chars.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `-cmatch` for case sensitive matching:

```
$str -cmatch '^[a-z][a-z0-9_]{3,7}$'
```

See [proof](https://regex101.com/r/jW4LFf/1)

**Explanation**

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  ^                        the beginning of the string
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  [a-z]                    any character of: 'a' to 'z'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  [a-z0-9_]{3,7}           any character of: 'a' to 'z', '0' to '9',
                           '_' (between 3 and 7 times (matching the
                           most amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  $                        before an optional \n, and the end of the
                           string
```

Answer (score 0):

[Ryszard Czech's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65835910/45375) shows the best solution.

As for **the regex you tried, `(^[a-z][a-z0-9_]+)(i){4,8}`**:

- Using a *quantifier* (e.g., `{4,8}`) on a subexpression (in this case, a capture group, `(...)`) that starts with `^` is pointless (leaving subexpression `(i)` aside - see below), because the start-of-input anchor `^` can by definition only match *once* at the start of the input.

  - Additionally, you're mistakenly applying an *additional* quantifier by placing `+` inside the capture group, which effectively matches the preceding subexpression, `[a-z0-9_]`, one or more times, with no limit placed on the number of matches.
- Given that only the *first* character must be limited to between `a` and `z` (`[a-z]`), only the subsequent `[a-z0-9_]` subexpression must be quantified, namely between `3` and `7` times, for an overall length between `4` and `8` characters.
- `(i)` looks like an attempt to use `i`, the *inline [regex option](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/regular-expression-options)* that specifies case-*insensitive* matching.

  - However, inline regex options require enclosing in `(?<option-letters>)`, where `<option-letters>` is a string of one or more option letters, optionally prefixed with `-` for turning options *off*.
  - Also, inline options only apply to the *remaining* part of the pattern (or enclosing explicit subexpression, `(...)`), so in order to use case-insensitive matching for the *entire* regex, place `(?i)` at the *start*.

Therefore:

```
'h8euj_' -match '(?i)^[a-z][a-z0-9_]{3,7}'
```

<sup>Note: Append end-of-input anchor `$` to ensure that the input string *as a whole* matches the regex.</sup>

However, as Ryszard's answer shows, using the `-cmatch` variant of the [`-match`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Comparison_Operators#-match) operator implicitly causes matching of the entire regex to be case-*sensitive*.

Other string-based PowerShell operators too offer `c`-prefixed variants for case-*sensitive* operation, given that their default behavior is to be case-*insensitive*.

To explicitly highlight the intent to be case-insensitive, you can also use `i`-prefixed variants, which are effective aliases of the operator's base name; e.g., `-imatch` is effectively the same as `-match`.